# scrape data with beautifulsoup results in 404

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to scrape data from the following URL `http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/wettbewerbe/europa`

I tpyically use BeautifulSoup for such a job. But this time, I get an *404 error*, but I don't know why, because I can access the page via the browser.

This is my code:

```
    url = 'http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/wettbewerbe/europa'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
    print(soup)
```

I get this error: `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found` at line 2.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import requests, bs4
url = 'http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/wettbewerbe/europa'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Add `User-Agent` to the requests header, I use `requests` library, you can use `urllib` to do the same

Comment: thanks mate. for the `print(soup)` i get another error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2261' in position 21727: character maps to <undefined>`. seems to be related to the character encoding?

Comment: update: i put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` into the header of my python-file. works now. thanks.