# Have made this scraper but the function returns no values? Just empty cells

Tags: python

So I've made a webscraper and everything seems to be running fine, however, no values are being returned? Assuming there's something wrong with the url but I can't seem to spot anything.

```
import pandas as pd 
    import datetime
    import requests
    from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    def web_content_div(web_content, class_path):
        web_content_div = web_content.find_all('div', {'class': class_path})
        try:
            spans = web_content_div[0].find_all('span')
            texts = [span.get_text() for span in spans]
        except IndexError:
            texts = []
    
        return texts
    
    def real_time_price(stock_code):
        url= 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock_code + '?p=' + stock_code + '&.tsrc=fin-tre-srch'
        try:
        
            r = requests.get(url)
            web_content = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
            texts = web_content_div(web_content, 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px) W(100%)')
            if texts != []:
              price, change = texts[0], texts[1]
            else:
              price, change = [], []
    
        except ConnectionError:
            price, change = [], []
    
        return price, change 
    
    Stock = ['BRK-B']
    print(real_time_price('BRK-B'))
```

Comment: Did you debug? What (which line) is returning "no value" (what is returned then) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scrape data with beautifulsoup results in 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909065/scrape-data-with-beautifulsoup-results-in-404)

Comment: Please search SO before you ask - this has to be one of the most commonly asked questions, and in almost all cases the answer is "User agent", "cookies" or "use `selenium` to enable JavaScript" - unless you've checked all three, it's pretty clear you didn't really make an effort to find an answer at all.

Answer (score -1):

Of course there may be different reasons for your problem and I can't jump into conclusions and suggest a generic solution to completely solve the problem.
First that I ran your code on my local, was getting `404` when making `requests.get` and thought that the `url` is malformed or wrong. Then I guessed python `requests`, having experienced some odd behavior before, is causing some problem and not getting what you want.
But then I guesssed, the problem may be due to the dynamic behaviour of the page, writing data into page with `javascript` or `xhr requests` or doing `document.write(sth)` to populate the page which causes the html file not to include actual data.
To cope with the `javascript` problem, I recommend using `selenium` or similar libraries. `Selenium` may also help you in cases a `pop-up` appears when you load the page, e.g. a dialog saying "do you consent to our rules or accept cookies or ..." and you can handle those conditions by clicking the right button.
Finally, you can Try using `user-agent` in your header which may some times be the case. I took a look at [your sites' robots.txt](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/robots.txt) and founded that it `Disallows` some agents, so it is always a good idea to change this parameter (and some others checked by the server). (Also try to separate your query `params`, which is much cleaner):

```
   ...
   url= 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock_code
   params = {
        'p': stock_code,
        '.tsrc': 'fin-tre-srch',
    }
    headers = {'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'}
    # alternatively: headers = {'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.4'}
    url = 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/BRK-B'
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
   ...
```

Comment: Sorry I think I may have worded this badly, by no values I meant im getting 0 errors but nothing is getting printed when i run the code. I think i'm missing something very basic:(

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with the URL, which you can easily check by running something like this from the command line (get `curl` for your OS if you don't have it):

```
curl --output result.txt "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/BRK-B?p=BRK-B&.tsrc=fin-tre-srch"
```

That works, and saves the text you're after in `result.txt`.

So, it's not the URL - usual suspect then is the user agent, and lo and behold, spoofing a normal web browser User Agent works just fine:

```
        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

This is just some random user agent string, you could try to find something more generic, but the key thing here is that Yahoo doesn't want to serve your Python script and you'll have to lie to Yahoo about what you're really doing to get what you want (which you do at your own risk, I'm not saying you should, I'm just saying how it's possible - don't).

Since you indicated the above "doesn't do it" - I can only assume you did try it and noticed that the content gets retrieved correctly, but the expression you pass to `find_all` gets you no results. That's because you cannot just pass all the classes in a single string separated by spaces: `'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px) W(100%)'`.

However, if you just pass `'smartphone_Mt(6px)'`, you'll notice that it only finds a single result anyway. With a bit more work, you can make a more specific selection, if needed for other elements.

Comment: Sorry to say that doesn't do it:) But I'll be sure to do some research this time aha!

Comment: It definitely does fix the 404 you'd otherwise get - but you may have additional issues in the way you're using `bs4`

Comment: Yes this is why i was confused, I was getting no errors, I am only getting ([],[]) as my results which i thought was strange seen as everything checks out. I've not used a user-agent when scraping yahoo finance before

Comment: Just seen your edit, thank you, I'll keep working on it so that i can get the stock prices.